# MySQL how do I select missing values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains employees and task, and I want a list of missing employee/task combinations.

```
Bob  Gardening
Bob  Watering
Jane Gardening
Jane Digging
```

so the select would yield

```
Bob  Digging
Jane Watering
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: There are probably three tables: employees, tasks and the mentioned employee_task table, correct? How are these linked? By ID or by string (e.g. 'Bob'  and 'Gardening')?

Comment: It is one table - it's a summary table created from other tables that lists employees and # of times an activity was done.

Answer (score 0):

A cross join creates all possible combinations of employees and task. With `NOT IN` you can subtract all existing employee/job combinations from this set:

```
select e.employee, t.task
from employees e
cross join task t
where (e.employee, t.task) not in
(
  select employee, task
  from employees_tasks
);
```

Comment: Thanks - this set me on the write path - i used  select * from ( select employee, task from (select distinct employee from table) as a  cross join (select distinct task from table) as b) as c  where (c.employee, c.task) not in (select employee, task from table);

Answer (score 0):

You need to take all employees as one subquery and all tasks as one more subquery and then do cross join. Once that is done give the condition as like below.

```
Select * from (
select a.employee,b.task from
(Select distinct employee from table) a, (select distinct task from table) b) where (employee,task) not in (select employee, task from table)
```